# How to define multiple types for input field in graphql nestjs

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server, dto

In the below code I want to define multiple types for the field **value ,**  current implementation only allows the first type (i.e., String).  but how can i define to expect any of these three types as input argument.

```
@InputType()
class RangeInput implements RangeInterface {
  @Field(type => String)
  start: string;

  @Field(type => String)
  end: string;
}

@InputType()
class KeyValuePair implements KeyValuePairInterface {
  @Field()
  key: string;

  @Field(() => [String, RangeInput, Number)
  value: string[] | RangeInput | number[];

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  matchExact: boolean;

  @Field(() => FilterType)
  filterType: FilterType;
}
```

I tried

```
@Field(() => [String, RangeInput, Number)
```

```
@Field(() => [Object)
```

```
@Field(() => [JSON)
```